# How to use boost::python::iterator with return_internal_reference?

Tags: c++, boost, reference, boost-python

I have a class `Type` which cannot be copied nor it contains default constructor.
I have second class `A` that acts as a set of the above classes. This second class gives access via iterators and my iterator has dereference operator:

```
class A {
    class iterator {
        [...]
      public:
        Type & operator*()
        { 
            return instance;
        }
      private:
        Type instance;
    }
    [...]
};
```

Now to expose that I wrote a `boost::python` code that looks like that:

```
class_<A>("A", [...])
    .def("__iter__", iterator<A, return_internal_reference<> >())
    .def("__len__", container_length_no_diff<A, A::iterator>)
;
```

After adding print messages to all iterator operations (construction, assignment, dereferences, destruction) for code Python like this:

```
for o in AInstance:
    print o.key
```

I get output (trimmed to important part):

```
construct 0xffffffff7fffd3e8
dereference: 0xffffffff7fffd3e8
destroy 0xffffffff7fffd3e8
get key 0xffffffff7fffd3e8
```

In above code those addresses are just addresses of `instance` member (or `this` in method call).
First three lines are produced by `iterator`, the fourth line is printed by getter method in `Type`. So somehow `boost::python` wraps everything in such manner that it:

1. creates iterator
2. dereferences iterator and stores reference
3. **destroys iterator (and object it contains)**
4. uses reference obtained in step two

So clearly `return_internal_reference` does not behave like stated (note that it actually is just typedef over `with_custodian_and_ward_postcall<>`) where it should keep object as long as result of method call is referenced.

So my question is how do I expose such an iterator to Python with `boost::python`?

**edit:**

As it was pointed out it might not be clear: the original container does not contain objects of type `Type`. It contains some `BaseType` objects from which I am able to construct/modify `Type` object. So `iterator` in above example acts like `transform_iterator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the whole problem was that I did not fully understand what semantics should `iterator` class provide.
It seems that value returned by iterator has to be valid as long as container exists, not iterator.

This  means that `boost::python` behaves correctly and there are two solutions to that:

- use `boost::shared_ptr`
- return by value

A bit less efficient approaches than what I tried to do, but looks like there is no other way.

**edit:**
I have worked out a solution (not only possible, but it seems to be working nicely): [Boost python container, iterator and item lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585575/boost-python-container-iterator-and-item-lifetimes)

Answer (score 1):

If `A` is a container that owns instances of `Type`, then consider having `A::iterator` contain a handle to `Type` instead of having a `Type`:

```
class iterator {
  [...]
private:
  Type* instance; // has a handle to a Type instance.
};
```

Instead of:

```
class iterator {
  [...]
private:
  Type instance; // has a Type instance.
};
```

In python, an iterator will contain a reference to the container on which it iterates.  This will extend the lifespan of an iterable object, and prevent the iterable object from being garbage collected during iteration.

```
>>> from sys import getrefcount
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> getrefcount(x)
2 # One for 'x' and one for the argument within the getrefcount function.
>>> iter = x.__iter__()
>>> getrefcount(x)
3 # One more, as iter contains a reference to 'x'.
```

`boost::python` supports this behavior.  Here is an example program, with `Foo` being a simple type that cannot be copied; `FooContainer` being an iterable container; and `FooContainer::iterator` being an iterator:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iterator>

// Simple example type.
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo()  { std::cout << "Foo constructed: " << this << std::endl; }
  ~Foo() { std::cout << "Foo destroyed:   " << this << std::endl; }
  void set_x( int x ) { x_ = x;    }
  int  get_x()        { return x_; }
private:
  Foo( const Foo& );            // Prevent copy.
  Foo& operator=( const Foo& ); // Prevent assignment.
private:
  int x_;  
};

// Container for Foo objects.
class FooContainer
{
private:
  enum { ARRAY_SIZE = 3 };
public:
  // Default constructor.
  FooContainer()
  {
    std::cout << "FooContainer constructed: " << this << std::endl;
    for ( int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i )
    {
      foos_[ i ].set_x( ( i + 1 ) * 10 );
    }
  }

  ~FooContainer()
  {
    std::cout << "FooContainer destroyed:   " << this << std::endl;
  }

  // Iterator for Foo types.  
  class iterator
    : public std::iterator< std::forward_iterator_tag, Foo >
  {
    public:
      // Constructors.
      iterator()                      : foo_( 0 )        {} // Default (empty).
      iterator( const iterator& rhs ) : foo_( rhs.foo_ ) {} // Copy.
      explicit iterator(Foo* foo)     : foo_( foo )      {} // With position.

      // Dereference.
      Foo& operator*() { return *foo_; }

      // Pre-increment
      iterator& operator++() { ++foo_; return *this; }
      // Post-increment.     
      iterator  operator++( int )
      {
        iterator tmp( foo_ );
        operator++();
        return tmp;
      }

      // Comparison.
      bool operator==( const iterator& rhs ) { return foo_ == rhs.foo_; }
      bool operator!=( const iterator& rhs )
      {
        return !this->operator==( rhs );
      }

    private:
      Foo* foo_; // Contain a handle to foo; FooContainer owns Foo.
  };

  // begin() and end() are requirements for the boost::python's 
  // iterator< container > spec.
  iterator begin() { return iterator( foos_ );              }
  iterator end()   { return iterator( foos_ + ARRAY_SIZE ); }
private:
  FooContainer( const FooContainer& );            // Prevent copy.
  FooContainer& operator=( const FooContainer& ); // Prevent assignment.
private:
  Foo foos_[ ARRAY_SIZE ];
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(iterator_example)
{
  using namespace boost::python;
  class_< Foo, boost::noncopyable >( "Foo" )
    .def( "get_x", &Foo::get_x )
    ;
  class_< FooContainer, boost::noncopyable >( "FooContainer" )
    .def("__iter__", iterator< FooContainer, return_internal_reference<> >())
    ;
}
```

Here is the example output:

```
>>> from iterator_example import FooContainer
>>> fc = FooContainer()
Foo constructed: 0x8a78f88
Foo constructed: 0x8a78f8c
Foo constructed: 0x8a78f90
FooContainer constructed: 0x8a78f88
>>> for foo in fc:
...   print foo.get_x()
... 
10
20
30
>>> fc = foo = None
FooContainer destroyed:   0x8a78f88
Foo destroyed:   0x8a78f90
Foo destroyed:   0x8a78f8c
Foo destroyed:   0x8a78f88
>>> 
>>> fc = FooContainer()
Foo constructed: 0x8a7ab48
Foo constructed: 0x8a7ab4c
Foo constructed: 0x8a7ab50
FooContainer constructed: 0x8a7ab48
>>> iter = fc.__iter__()
>>> fc = None
>>> iter.next().get_x()
10
>>> iter.next().get_x()
20
>>> iter = None
FooContainer destroyed:   0x8a7ab48
Foo destroyed:   0x8a7ab50
Foo destroyed:   0x8a7ab4c
Foo destroyed:   0x8a7ab48
```

Comment: So kinda the same I came up with myself. Also pure `Type* instance;` will be hard to track down I think and some kind of shared pointer is a better way. Especially that `boost::python` supports it with (almost?) none effort.
Also that approach has a drawback of being slowed down by allocations, so I finally went for implementing copy constructor and returning by value (though I would have to do some testing to say for sure it is faster than allocating data for pointer).

Comment: And I think you missed the point totally. I have some kind of `transform_iterator`. Instances of objects I want to return do not exist anywhere. Container does not contain objects of `Type`, but something that allows me to construct `Type`.

Comment: @elmo: You may want to consider updating the original question to reflect those requirements/intentions, cause at the moment there is no reference to `transform_iterator`, and there is a suggestion that the `Type` objects you want to return are contained within `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is relevant sample:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/iterator.
You can **return iterator value** by const / non const **reference**:

```
...
.def("__iter__"
     , range<return_value_policy<copy_non_const_reference> >(
           &my_sequence<heavy>::begin
         , &my_sequence<heavy>::end))
```

The idea is that, as you mentioned, you should bind to the container lifetime instead of the iterator lifetime for the return value.