# Boost python container, iterator and item lifetimes

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

I am trying to expose C++ container to Python.
I have:

```
class Container {
    std::auto_ptr<Iterator> __iter__();
};

class Iterator {
    Container & parent;
    Item __next__();
};

class Item {
    Container & parent;
};
```

`Item` class internally references data that exists in Container. `Iterator` which returned `Item` instance doesn't have to exist for `Item` to be usable.

```
c = Container()
for i in c:
    store = i

print store
```

In above code I would expect to get `Container`, `Iterator` and few `Item` instances.
When it reaches `print` statement I would expect `Iterator` to be already destructed, but `Container` instance has obviously still exist for `store`.

Now here comes the problem. I don't know what `CallPolicy` to use to achieve that effect:
Defining:

```
class_<Container>("Container", ...)
  .def("__iter__", &Container::__iter__, return_interal_reference<>() )
;

class_<Iterator>("Iterator", ...)
  .def("next", &Iterator::__next__, what_call_policy_here? )
;

class_<Item>("Item", ...)
  .def("__str__", ... )
;
```

What should I use in place of `what_call_policy_here`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after long digging I think I came up with solution that is transparent to exposed type.

## Short description

Basically solution was to create `CallPolicy` that will automatically store reference to *parent* object (i.e. `Container`) inside returned *child* object (i.e. `Iterator`) as its attribute (I used a private name, but Python is quite liberal in that matter).

Then automatically copy this to all *sibling* objects (*sibling* is another *child* of *parent*, but one that was created with a call to method of another *child*, so not directly from *parent*).

## Implementation

This required a bit of fiddling with `CallPolicy`. I had to create two custom ones:

```
// This policy is used for methods returning items that require object to be
// kept as long as return thing is alive.
// It stores reference in attribute named Property_::name
template <typename Property_, class BasePolicy_ = boost::python::default_call_policies>
struct store_parent_reference: public BasePolicy_
{
    template <class ArgumentPackage>
    static PyObject* postcall(ArgumentPackage const& args_, PyObject* result)
    {
        result = BasePolicy_::postcall(args_, result);

        PyObject* parent = detail::get_prev< std::size_t(1) >::execute(args_, result);
        PyObject* child = result;

        if( PyObject_SetAttrString( child, Property_::name, parent ) == -1 )
        {
            std::ostringstream err;
            err << "store_parent_reference::postcall could not set attribute `"                    << Property_::name
                << "` on newly allocated object `"
                << extract<std::string>( object( handle<>(borrowed(child))).attr("__str__")() )()
                << "`";
            throw std::runtime_error(err.str());
        }



        return result;
    }
};


// This policy is used for methods returning "sibling" in the meaning both the returned object
// and one that has this method called on require "parent" object to be alive.
//
// It copies reference to "parent" to attribute named ChildProperty_::name
// from "original" object's attribute named SiblingProperty_::name
template <typename ChildProperty_, typename SiblingProperty_ = ChildProperty_, class BasePolicy_ = boost::python::default_call_policies>
struct copy_parent_from_sibling: public BasePolicy_
{
    template <class ArgumentPackage>
    static PyObject* postcall(ArgumentPackage const& args_, PyObject* result)
    {
        result = BasePolicy_::postcall(args_, result);

        PyObject* sibling = detail::get_prev< std::size_t(1) >::execute(args_, result);
        PyObject* new_child = result;

        PyObject* parent = PyObject_GetAttrString( sibling, SiblingProperty_::name );

        if( parent == NULL )
        {
            std::ostringstream err;
            err << "copy_parent_from_sibling::postcall could not get attribute `"
                << SiblingProperty_::name
                << "` from sibling `"
                << extract<std::string>( object( handle<>(borrowed(sibling))).attr("__str__")() )()
                << "` to set up attribute `"
                << ChildProperty_::name
                << "` of returned object which is `"
                << extract<std::string>( object( handle<>(borrowed(new_child))).attr("__str__")() )()
                << "`";
            throw std::runtime_error(err.str());
        }

        if( PyObject_SetAttrString( new_child, ChildProperty_::name, parent ) == -1 )
        {
            std::ostringstream err;
            err << "copy_parent_from_sibling::postcall could not set attribute `"
                << ChildProperty_::name
                << "` on returned object which is `"
                << extract<std::string>( object( handle<>(borrowed(new_child))).attr("__str__")() )()
                << "`";
            throw std::runtime_error(err.str());
        }

        Py_DECREF(parent);

        return result;
    }
};
```

## Usage

Now the usage:

```
struct ContainerProperty {
    static const char * const name;
};
const char * const ContainerProperty::name = "__container"

class_<Container>("Container", ...)
    .def("__iter__", &Container::__iter__, store_parent_reference< ContainerProperty >() )
;

class_<Iterator>("Iterator", ...)
    .def("next", &Iterator::__next__, copy_parent_from_sibling< ContainerProperty >() )
;

class_<Item>("Item", ...)
;
```

**Note**: It is hard to give complete minimal working sample for `boost::python` stuff, so I might have missed some detail above, but solution seems to be working fine for me (I was tracking destructor calls to check).

Also this is not the only solution. Notice that `store_parent_reference` is somewhat similar to `return_internal_reference` with the difference it explicitly needs a place to store data. This is only because `copy_parent_from_sibling` needs to copy it from somewhere.

Main benefit of this approach is that it does not require original classes to be aware of Python stuff.