# Why Python doesn't catch exceptions raised in C++?

Tags: python, c++, exception, python-3.x, boost-python

I am trying to make a Python iterator in boost::python. So I have a function

```
PyObject *my_iterator_next(MyIterator *iter) {
    if (!iter->is_end()) {
        return *(*iter)++;
    }
    else {
        PyErr_SetNone(PyExc_StopIteration);
        // this doesn't work either
        // PyErr_SetString(PyExc_StopIteration, "end of collection");
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

In Python:

```
// x is MyContainer([1, 2, 3])
for x in my_container:
    print(x)
```

And I get:

```
1
2
3
NoneTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(x)
StopIteration: end of collection
```

Also

```
it = my_collection.__iter__()
try:
    it.__next__();
    it.__next__();
    it.__next__();
    it.__next__();
except:
    print("caught exception")
```

This code doesn't print anything, so no type of exception is caught.

Why?

Comment: If the underlying iterator is a C++ iterator, then it may be worth using [`boost::python::iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/python/doc/v2/iterator.html), as it handles all the subtle details (such as having the iterator extend the life of the container).  This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11299759/1053968) demonstrates its usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting the Python exception, you must notify Boost.Python like this:

```
throw_error_already_set();
```

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/python/doc/v2/errors.html